# Android App crashing while making post request with jsonparser

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask

This is the logcat error which I am gettingsponse is totally ok but dont know whyit is not working

JSON re

```
06-24 03:20:38.830: E/JSON Parser(15245): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <!DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject



{"status":{"type":"Error","msg":"Authorization Required"}}
```

---

```
{
    "data": {
        "access_token": "3c2e2bdce081bdfd31f75f2cb26855e9",
        "user": {
            "client_id": 0,
            "user_type_id": 0
        }
    },
    "status": {
        "type": "success",
        "action": "login"
    }
}}
```

Comment: post ur json data structure. Coz as per the error you are trying to parse string by creating jsonobject.

Answer (score 0):

You are simply not parsing a valid JSON string. Are you sure you are calling the correct URL for your data? You can try by using the chrome plugin [postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm).

You can validate the JSON output with this [JSON validator](http://jsonlint.com/)

Note that a JSON Object has the following form:

```
{
    "key": "value",
    "key2": "value2"
}
```

And a JSON Array the following:

```
[
    {
        "key": "value",
        "key2": "value2"
    },
    {
        "key": "value",
        "key2": "value2"
    }
]
```

Comment: Thanks for replying .... How can I pass the value of header from activity to jsonparser class (i.e, passing the value from activity to class)??

Comment: @RahulSaxena I am not sure what you mean, but if you want to use a separate class for JSON parsing (which I would encourage), you can just create an instance of this parser and call methods on it or let is have static methods which you would call directly.